# keynav jquery plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

i am unable to move a highlighter div on a(any) web page whose locomotion is enabled only with the helpof the 4 arrow keys (and  the fifth key(with key code of 13)) I dont know anything about what is the fifth key and its purpose. I am using the keynav plugin for the purpose and some extra code for inserting the highlighter into it but all in vain

Answer (score 1):

If it is the [jquery.keynav](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/keynav) plugin that you are using, then it works just fine, even with the latest jQuery (v1.6.1). In computing, the ASCII is a character encoding scheme and `13` is 
the number of the <kbd>↵</kbd> (Enter) key (see [ASCII Control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#In_ASCII)).

The jQuery plugin is designed for the arrow keys <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> to move the *selection box* around and the <kbd>↵</kbd> key to fire the [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event.

Here is a demo that uses the plugin. You will need to save the [plugin code](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.keynav.1.1.txt) as *jquery.keynav.js* and put that file in the same directory as the demo code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.keynav.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#keynavDemo div').keynav('keynav_focusbox','keynav_box');
            $('#keynavDemo div:first').removeClass().addClass('keynav_focusbox'); // give first div focus (optional)
            $('#keynavDemo div').click(function() {
                alert('key 13');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #keynavDemo {
            position:relative;  
        }
        .keynav_box, .keynav_focusbox {
            position:absolute;
            height:30px;
            width:30px; 
            border:1px solid black;
        }
        .keynav_box {
            background-color:green;
        }
        .keynav_focusbox {
            background-color:red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="keynavDemo"> 
        <div class='keynav_box' style='left:0px'>0:0</div>
        <div class='keynav_box' style='left:50px'>0:1</div>
        <div class='keynav_box' style='left:100px'>0:2</div>
        <div class='keynav_box' style='left:150px'>0:3</div>
        <div class='keynav_box' style='left:200px'>0:4</div>
        <div class='keynav_box' style='left:250px'>0:5</div>
        <div class='keynav_box' style='left:300px'>0:6</div>
        <div class='keynav_box' style='left:350px'>0:7</div>
        <div class='keynav_box' style='left:400px'>0:8</div>
        <div class='keynav_box' style='left:450px'>0:9</div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Credit to the [plugin author](http://mike-hostetler.com/jquery-keyboard-navigation-plugin), where I "borrowed" the demo from :-)

Comment: thanx for the answer now i just want you to see this 
and I am sure you will solve the woes of the code which continues

Comment: thanx for the answer now i just want you to see this 
and I am sure you will solve the woes of the code which continues
see this 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109193/jquer-keynav-not-working-after-adding-new-code