# keycode 13 is for which key

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, keyboard

Which is the key on the keyboard having the keycode as `13`?

```
switch(key) {
  case 37: 
    $.keynav.goLeft();
    break;
  case 38: 
    $.keynav.goUp();
    break;
  case 39: 
    $.keynav.goRight();
    break;
  case 40: 
    $.keynav.goDown();
    break;
  case 13: 
    $.keynav.activate();
    break;
}
```

Comment: The `key` variable in this `switch` is either `e.which` or `e.keyCode`. Those two are deprecated, so you should use `e.key` instead, which will also make your code more readable by turning those numbers into descriptive strings: `ArrayUp`, `ArrowRight`, `ArrowDown`, `ArrowLeft` and `Enter`. You can check out the key codes and identifiers for any key by just pressing them on this site: https://keyjs.dev

Answer (score 229):

It's the <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on keyboard.

Answer (score 56):

That would be the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: How did you create the "key effect" for the Enter phrase in your answer?

Comment: thanx for the answer but what i really want is this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086316/keynav-jquery-plugin-not-working

Comment: @Sarwar Erfan: using `<kbd>Enter</kbd>`

Answer (score 40):

Check an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

It stands for `CR`, or Carriage Return, AKA the <kbd>Return</kbd> key.

Comment: I like this answer better than others because it shows HOW you knew that 13 was a carriage return. I found https://www.ascii-code.com/ easier to use.

Answer (score 14):

Keycode 13 is the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

[Which keycode for escape key with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160008/which-keycode-for-escape-key-with-jquery)

Comment: These are the Js [key-codes](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

Answer (score 12):

The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key should have the keycode 13. Is it not working?

Answer (score 11):

Keycode 13 means the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

If you would want to get more keycodes and what the key the key is, go to: https://keycode.info

Comment: @Danziger Oh I haven't seen that website before! Nice!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer to be honest.

Answer (score 6):

key 13 keycode is for ENTER key.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function myFunction(event) {
  var x = event.charCode;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The Unicode value is: " + x;
}
```

```html
<p>Keycode 13 is: </p> 
<button>Enter</button>
<p>Press a key on the keyboard in the input field to get the Unicode character code of the pressed key.</p>
<b>You can test in below</b>

<input type="text" size="40" onkeypress="myFunction(event)">

<p id="demo"></p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The charCode property is not supported in IE8 and earlier versions.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working for me.
Using "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31636924)