# How do you simulate an keyDown enter event (or others) in Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I'm trying to simulate a `keyDown` event, specifically for Enter, `keyCode: 13`. I've tried a number of different ways of doing this, but none of them are working. I've also looked online and it seems like this feature is either buggy or not working in the current version of Enzyme. Does anyone know definitively if this feature works, and if so, what is the proper syntax for simulating an enter, or other types of key events? Thanks!

This is what I have currently, and it's not working:

```
const input = wrapper.find('input');
input.simulate('keyDown', {keyCode: 13});
```

My current Enzyme version is 2.4.1

Comment: That should work. Are you using `shallow` or `mount`?

Comment: @ZekeDroid is there any sure way to verify that it's working? My test of whether it's working or not involves checking if a new component is created, and in this case, that's not happening. Also, I've had issues with both `sinon` and `chai`'s spy utilities in enzyme, so I haven't been able to use those to verify user events.

Comment: I would add an `onChange` event to your input field and console.log every event. Then run your test and see if you get the `keyDown` event

Comment: Where are these simulate-able events documented? The airbnb docs only mention 'click', not e.g., keypress or keyDown[sic]. Are they borrowed from the WebAPI somewhere?

Comment: This works with enzyme 3.1.0 using mount. Event name is `keydown`

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Instead of using a keyCode, I used a key, in the case of 'Enter', using `mount`:

```
wrapper.find('input').simulate('keypress', {key: 'Enter'})
```

Comment: It worked for me, and to clarify, I am using Enzyme with Jest.

Comment: oh I got the problem. "keyPress" should be "keypress". Worked for me!!

Comment: I struggled with this, but remembered I was using the keyDown event instead of keyPress. Good to keep that in mind if you're stuck.

Comment: it sucks that there's nothing about this in the official docs!

Comment: This will not work with onKeyDown, you need to use `.simulate('keydown', { key: 'Enter' });` that is if your check is `if (e.key === 'Enter')`

Comment: Official docs: https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulate.md

Answer (score 26):

I'm using 'shallow' mount (Enzyme 3.7.0 with Jest 23.6.0). This work for me:

```
const input = wrapper.find('input');
input.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'abcdefg'} });
input.simulate('keydown', { keyCode: 13 });
```

Comment: where do these keycode constants come from? Couldn't find with a quick google search

Comment: It is actually the index number in the ASCII table. Based on the ASCII table (http://www.asciitable.com/), number 13 represents Carriage Return (means ENTER key).

Someone raised the same question at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086686/keycode-13-is-for-which-key

Answer (score 18):

**Simulate solution is deprecated**

Enzyme simulate is supposed to be removed in version 4. Main maintainer is suggesting directly invoking prop functions. One solution is to directly test that invoking those props does the right thing; or you can mock out instance methods, test that the prop functions call them and unit test the instance methods.

You could call key down for example

```
wrapper.find('input').prop('onKeyDown')({ key: 'Enter' })
```

or

```
wrapper.find('input').props().onKeyDown({ key: 'Enter' })
```

Information about deprecation: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2173

Comment: Thanks for giving that deprecation context!

Answer (score 10):

```
wrapper.find('input').simulate('keydown');
```

It worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

```
const wrapper = mount(<App />);
const input = wrapper.find('input');
input.props().onKeyDown({key: 'Enter'});
```

- Enzyme 3.9.0
- React 16.8.6

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this forum. Please edit your answer to include a description of what your code does and how it will solve OP's problems.

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends on the implementation.  If you've used something like this in your implementation:

```
if (event.charCode === 13) {
  // do something
}
```

you would simulate the event in your test like this:

```
wrapper.find('input').simulate('keypress', { charCode: 13 });
```

Hope it helps :-).

Answer (score 1):

This solution is working perfectly:

```
wrapper.find('#id1').simulate('keyDown', {key: 'ArrowRight'});
wrapper.find('#id2').simulate('keyDown', {key: 'Enter'})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to simulate a Event while shallowing an Element you could mock the `document.addEventListener` method:

```
let events = [];
document.addEventListener = jest.fn((event, cb) => {
    events[event] = cb;
});

shallow(<YourElement/>);

// trigger the keypress event
events.keyup({key: 's'});

// your test expectations
expect(someMethod).toBeCalledTimes(1);
```