# jQuery.keynav not working after adding new code

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the jquery.keynav plugin to perform navigation on a webpage using the five keys. 
The problem resides in the fact that I am using a highlighter div which guides the user through the web page what ever is in the div (text etc) can be fetched and several operations may be performed
but the highlighter div is not working rather it is contained at the top left corner of the web page(any web page). Here is the code. The code was added to move the highlighter.

```
var offset = $('.'+e.onClass).offset();

$('#monitor').html($.htmlClean($('.'+e.onClass).html()));

$('#highlighter').animate({'height' : $('.'+e.onClass).height() + 10, 'left' : (offset.left - 6) + 'px', 'top' : (offset.top - 10) + 'px', 'width' : $('.'+e.onClass).width() + 12 }, 300);

//$('#highlighter').scrollIntoView(true);
```

**Editor:** This seems to be a continuation of [keynav jquery plugin not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086316/keynav-jquery-plugin-not-working/)

Comment: Can you add a working example of the problem? Without HTML, CSS and JavaScript it is unlikely that anyone will be able to help. You can edit the question and add more code.

Comment: can follow this link hopw this is of some help


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086316/keynav-jquery-plugin-not-working/6088253#6088253

Comment: I need more example code. Can you please post an example of the HTML, CSS and JavaScript that is not working. You could use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) to create a demo.